# react-native redux dispatch action from nested components

Tags: react-native, redux

I am wondering how I can dispatch an action from n-th level nested components. This is wha I have got:

BodyContainer (contains connect, mapProps, mapDispatch, etc.) => Body

=Body (Component) where the actions are dispatched)

==Grid (Component)- state is passed as props from Body and some elements parts of the state are further passed on to the next component as props.

===Square (Component) - receives some part of the state as props.

Now, I'd like to dispatch an action from the Square component to change the state. I thought I'll just do a SquareContainer first but then how would it get the parts of the state from Grid?

See below the components (let me know if you need more information):

BodyContainer:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { listNumbers, pickNumber } from '../actions/numberActions';
import { populateRow, populateGrid } from '../actions/gridActions';
import Body from '../components/Body';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  numbers: state.numbers,
  grid: state.grid
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators({
    listNumbers,
    pickNumber,
    populateRow,
    populateGrid
  }, dispatch)
);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Body);
```

Body Component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Grid from './Grid';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';


export default class Body extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh() {
    this.props.populateGrid();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <Grid inGrid={this.props.grid} />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.refresh.bind(this)}
            title={'Regenerate the Grid'}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Grid component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Square from './Square';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';

export default class Grid extends Component {
  render() {
    const row = [];
    let i = 0;
    this.props.inGrid.forEach((r) => {
      r.forEach((c) => {
        i++;
        row.push(
          <Square key={i} sqValue={c} />
        );
      });
    });
    const { grid } = styles;
    return (
      <View style={grid}>
        {row}
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Square Component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';

const Square = ({ sqValue }) => {
  const { square, textStyle, squareActive } = styles;
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      style={[square, sqValue[1] && squareActive]}
      onPress={() => console.log(sqValue[0])}
    >
      <View>
        <Text style={textStyle}>{sqValue[0]},{sqValue[1]}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
};
```

Edit: I've changed the Square component to a stateful one:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import * as globalStyles from '../styles/global';


export default class Square extends Component {
  render() {
    const { square, textStyle, squareActive } = styles;
    const { sqValue } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={[square, sqValue[1] && squareActive]}
        onPress={() => console.log(sqValue[0])}
      >
        <View>
          <Text style={textStyle}>{sqValue[0]},{sqValue[1]}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

I'd like to dispatch an action from onPress={}. Thank you

Comment: Just keep passing, whatever action you want to dispatch, down to square component as a prop and then in square component simply call this.props.myAction()

Comment: Thanks - I have managed to do it.

Comment: @Wasteland Can you please post how did you manage to do this?